# retrieve the value of a custom field depending on the value of a custom member field

Tags: parse-order

I have a custom member field that can have a value of "1", "2" or "3"

In channel entries I need to output the value of one of three custom fields, depending the member field value.

ie : {field_{member_field}}

I've tried to put together a plugin but I'm a bit stuck in parsing order issues.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on what you've tried? My first thought is to use a mapping array in the plugin (map 1 to field_id_48, map 2 to field_id_whatever, etc...)

Comment: The plugin just checks the value of the logged in member's custom field and outputs it to the template. Then in the template I've tried {field_{exp:my_plugin}} but the template outputs {field_1} which would be correcte if only it was parsed by the template engine !

Answer (score 0):

If it can help anyone, here is how I solved it:

1 - Forget the plugin idea

2 - Allow PHP on input in the template

3 - Query the database to get the custom member profile field value

```
    $member_id = ee()->session->userdata('member_id');

    if ( $member_id ) {

        $results = ee()->db->select('m_field_id')
            ->from('exp_member_data')
            ->where(array(
                'member_id' => $member_id
            ))
            ->get();

        $value = $results->row('m_field_id');

    }
```

4 - echo the php value in the template tag

```
{field_<?=$value?>}
```

Comment: That would do it. of if you wanted a PHP-less solution you could use an embed to defeat parse order (embed variables are parsed before module tags so pass the `{member_field}` as a parameter to the embed, and in the embed do `{field_{embed:var}}`. Might work, might not. Don't forget to come back and tick your answer as _the_answer in 2 days!!